# javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: jpa, junit

i have a problem with a JPA project that is connected with a EE project, i have done the tests (JUnit 4) for the DAOs in a source package with a persistence.xml only for this test units.
when i'm going to test them they get me this error, like if the unit tests can not found the persistence provider.
please some one help me.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistence Provider can't be found refers to JPA provider Jar file not being included into your test environment. Make sure JPA provider (Hibernate/ OpenJPA or whatever is provided with your app server) jar is available in classpath from where your test case reads dependent libraries.